# What do i do with this 'Tag of Sharpness I' that I got in the beginning of the game

Tags: perfect-world

It says to redeem this at the mailbox but How do I use it to get the Perfect Military Magic sword. I just started Perfect World yesterday. I am only level 7 by the way.

Answer (score 2):

When you trade the Tag of Sharpness into the mailbox/post office, you can choose from the following items - The Perfect Military Dualhammer, the Perfect Military Magicsword, or the Perfect Military Longbow. So if it is the Military Magicsword you are after, you can apparently just pick it up when you trade in the Tag.

Comment: Lol thanks ... I ended up figuring it out right after I posted the question. I am like lvl 21 now :)